# SplitViewController Based Application in iOS5

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller

In iOS 5, I have created a splitViewController based application in which I have a tableview in the MasterViewController and a label in the DetailViewController. When I select any row in the table, I want to show that value in the DetailViewController label.

In the DetailViewController the label displays the value for the first time but it does not work when I select a row in the tableView. When I select any row, data comes to the DetailViewController but does not load in the label.

Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [tutorial](http://www.scienceathand.com/idevblogaday/adventures-in-uisplitviewcontroller-2/) for iOS 5. I hope they will help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the row in the table and when the data does come to the detailviewcontroller, do you do anything to reload that label? I think that is the problem